# Is there an alternative to publicize.exe?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

The Visual Studio unit test tool `publicize.exe` appears to be unsupported.  Bugs aren't getting fixed in it and I'm hitting blocking bugs where it crashes when creating private accessor assemblies for perfectly valid assemblies.

Do any alternative tools exist for publicize.exe?

(I'm aware of `InternalsVisibleTo`, and the arguments for testing only public surface area, blah blah blah... this question is not an invitation for a philosophical debate)

Comment: DIY: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/testnonpublicmembers.aspx

Comment: I'm familiar with the reflection approach, which is what a private accessor assembly such as one generated by publicize.exe uses internally.  But reflection doesn't generate compile-time errors when refactoring the assembly being tested, whereas using a tool such as publicize.exe at compile-time guarantees compile-time errors where types or members no longer exist. Thanks though.